# Bijection from two open intervals to one

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was thinking about a bijection between the extended complex plane and the complex plane. Realising that the complex plane could be further reduced to the open unit disc (by mapping every polar coordinate $(r,\phi)$ to $(2\sigma(r)-1, \phi)$ where $\sigma$ is the sigmoid function), the only problem left was to consider a bijection from the open unit disc to an union of the open unit disc with the point at infinity. Simplifying things, I have reduced my problem to finding a bijection between an open interval on the real number line to a closed-open interval, which can further be reduced to this:

Consider open intervals $A$, $B$ and $C$ on the real number line such that $A$ and $B$ don't have any elements in common. Is it possible to define a bijection between $A\cup{B}$ to $C$?

Example case: Does there exist a bijection between $(0,0.5)\cup(0.5,1)$ and $(0,1)$ ?

Comment: Yes. It is always possible, even when A and B has some common segment.

Comment: Both sets are of size continuum, so there is bijection between them.

Comment: @ShyamalSayak could you please prove why it is so by describing an implicit (or if you prefer, explicit) bijection?

Comment: @Jakobian could you please give some kind of implicit bijection for the example case?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933). Could *you* please edit your post to include *some* personal work?

Comment: @AnneBauval sorry for the mistake. Could you please check if my edit follows the standards?

Comment: Having added you motivation is excellent and might be considered as sufficient. It would have been even better if you did add some attempts even if they failed. But don't bother: I shall find one of the many duplicates showing that $(0,1)$ and $(0,1]$ are equinumerous, since you wrote that is what you want.

Comment: @AnneBauval, so I should have like written about my thoughts on how to solve it, and then posed my question? Actually it’s my first question on this SE…

Comment: 1) motivation 2) question 3) attempt(s). For more guidance, follow the 2 links in my 1st comment above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving intervals are equinumerous to $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226677/proving-intervals-are-equinumerous-to-mathbb-r) or that? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226659/proving-intervals-are-equinumerous

Comment: @AnneBauval actually in that question the OP has already considered many things as being already taught while I don’t have that kind of prerequisites. But found this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160738/how-to-define-a-bijection-between-0-1-and-0-1

Comment: Excellent! Have a nice stay on this site :-) https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Intervals+equinumerous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$f=\begin{cases}2x,&x\in\{\frac14,\frac18,\frac16,\dotsb\}\\
x,&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
Then $f:(0,0.5)\cup(0.5,1)\to(0,1)$ is a bijection.

Note that this function is discontinuous at infinitely many points (all points of the form $1/2^n$). It can be shown that there is no bijection between these sets that only uses finitely many points of discontinuity.

Comment: Is there any way I can mark 2 answers as correct?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Could you refer a proof for the inexistence of bijection with "finitely many points of discontinuity"?

Comment: And that would imply the absence of any continuous bijection, right?

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it. Moreover, this is certainly a mega-dupe.

Comment: @AnneBauval While I agree that the question is a duplicate, I disagree that it is low-quality.

Comment: It was at the time you answered it. I did my best to guide the OP.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger am I right in thinking that no continuous bijection can exist for my example case since a continuous bijection can’t be established between a connected and a disconnected set? (Inspired from https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-prove-or-disprove-that-there-exists-a-continuous-bijection-from-mathbb-R-2-to-mathBB-R-real-analysis-general-topology-analysis-elementary-set-theory-math)

Comment: @SohamSaha There's a continuous bijection from $(0,1)\cup[2,3)$ to $(0,2)$ (subtract $1$ from the second piece). However, the inverse function is not continuous, and there is no continuous bijection from $(0,2)$ to $(0,1)\cup[2,3)$.

Comment: (A continuous function with continuous inverse is called a "homeomorphism".)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explicit bijection from $(0, 1)$ to $(0, 1/2) \cup (1/2, 1)$:  Map 1/2 to 1/4, 1/4 to 1/8, 1/8 to 1/16, etc.  For all other values of $x$, map $x$ to $x$.

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it. Moreover, this is certainly a mega-dupe.